# My webpack bundle isn't sent with Express app.get('/*')

Tags: node.js, express, webpack

I'am have a bundle.js file that is attached with my index.html. I use a dynamic path at first :

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {

      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/src/index.html'));

  });
```

When I connect to localhost:8080/something, the html is sent but the div where the bundle is supposed to be displayed is empty.

But when I change the path to static one (like `app.get('/',..)`) and connect to localhost:8080/, the bundle is displayed.

How can I make this work with a dynamic path?

Comment: Define a static route *before* you define all the http verbs, by adding `app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/src')));`.

Comment: It's already done : `app.use(express.static('dist'));`, my dist file contains the bundle.js . And it already works with a static path.

Comment: are you using webpack-dev server?

Comment: @WitVault No I only use webpack

Comment: just make sure that your static assets are generated in that folder and are not in memory.

Comment: They are in the folder. What bothers me is that it works whenever I use a static route...

Comment: So are you trying to get `/dist/bundles.js` from your HTML page?

Comment: @noChance Yes that is what I'am trying to do, and it works when using a static route like app.get('/',...)

Comment: What is the `src` in your `<script>`?

Comment: It's just the folder containing the index.html file that I'am displaying when connecting to localhost.

Comment: Add `app.use('/dist', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));.` The  way you do it with `app.use(express.static('dist'));` will just GET /bundles.js instead of /dist/bundles.js.

Comment: So why is it working when using a static route?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144652/discussion-between-nochance-and-mit).